# Displaying the date with a specific format isn't working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

Trying to formate the DateTime to Date in ViewModel but it does'nt work.

ViewModel

```
   [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? TargetCompletionDate { get; set; }
```

View

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TargetCompletionDate, new { style = "width: 100px;" })
```

Comment: It displays the time field too (3/31/2014 12:00:00 AM)

Comment: Working on my side. Is it not displaying correctly in display mode?

Comment: It was displaying the default time and when i changed it to @Html.EditorFor it worked perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

(Solved)I made it as @Html.EditorFor and works fine.
Thanks.

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.TargetCompletionDate, new { style = "width: 100px;" })
```